# How to write the below powershell command in .net to get certificate info so that we cam pass it in a REST call?

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, certificate

How to write the below powershell command in .net to get certificate info so that we can pass it in a REST call?

'`Get-ChildItem -Path 'cert:\LocalMachine\My' | Where-Object { $_.Thumbprint -eq '<ThumbPrint>' }`'

## The location shown here is from Certlm.msc. Local certificate store.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

X509Store store = new X509Store("my", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "854b0e801b16e1b43ba003132588ac6894eb010a", false);
X509Certificate2 certificate = col[0];
```

Test
[image]